# Collecting Files From Many Machines?

Tags: linux, file, networking, rsync, nfs

I have many machines (20+) connected in a network. each machine accesses a central database, queries it, processes the information queried, and then writes the results to files on its local hard drive.

Following the processing, I'd like to be able to 'grab' all these files (from all the remote machines) back to the main machine for storage.

I thought of three possible ways to do so:

(1) rsync to each remote machine from the main machine, and 'ask' for the files

(2) rsync from every remote machine to the main machine, and 'send' the files

(3) create a NFS share on each remote machine, to which the main machine can access and read the files (no 'rsync' is needed in such a case)

Is one of the ways better than others? are there better ways I am not aware of?

All machines use Ubuntu 10.04LTS. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could create *one* NFS share on the master machine and have each remote machine mount that. Seems like less work.

Comment: I agree. The question is, wouldn't the whole process be so slow since the main machine's hard drive can only handle so much? (imagine there are 20+ machines sending GBs of information to it each...)

Comment: Well, you didn't specify the size of the files. Does the processing all have to be done the same time? Or can you stagger it?

Comment: most of the processing is done at the same time. do you have any other ideas in mind on how to improve this process?

Comment: Well, you could process them all at once, and delay the copy by n minutes, where n is (length of the copy) x (machine id), where machine ID is from 0 to m.

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise, it's practically the same. You are still sending files over a (relatively) slow network connection.

Now, I'd say which approach you take depends on where you want to handle errors or irregularities. If you want the responsibility to lie on your processing computers, use rsync back to the main one; or the other way round if you want the main one to work on assembling the data and assuring everything is in order.

As for the shared space approach, I would create **a share on the main machine**, and have the others write to it. They can start as soon as the processing finishes, ensure the file is transferred correctly, and then verify checksums or whatever.

Comment: thank you Santiago. Are there any ways to improve the performance even further?

Comment: well, I'm no expert here, but I'd say it really depends on the amount of computation and the size of the results file you want to send back. If each file is big, you might want to handle the tasks to the working machines in such a way that they don't all finish at the same time and then struggle to get their results across the network, but other than that, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer option (2) since you know when the processing is finished on the client machine. You could use the same SSH key on all client machines or collect the different keys in the authorized_keys file on the main machine. It's also more reliable if the main machine is unavailable for some reason, you can still sync the results later while in the NFS setup the clients are blocked.

Comment: thanks. Is (2) better than simply mounting as the other answers suggested?

Comment: It depends. I would favour setting up a SSH key infrastructure over setting up NFS, but this is also a matter of taste. For very large files the encryption could be a CPU overhead compared to NFS.